# Query to find all lines connected to other

Tags: sql, oracle-dbms, oracle-spatial

I have problem with one spatial (Oracle) query. Simplified overview of the problem is:

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE thin_lines (
  id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  geom SDO_GEOMETRY),
  color VARCHAR2(32);

CREATE TABLE thick_lines (
  id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  geom SDO_GEOMETRY),
  color VARCHAR2(32);
```

Both tables contain 2D lines. The example picture:

[image]

The problem:

I want to create SQL query or PL/SQL procedure to find ids of all blue thin lines (whole blue branch comprising of blue lines) connected to the thick green lines.

Comment: For doing it properly you should handle your lines as a network http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28399/sdo_net_concepts.htm. Does your license allow use of SDO_NET package?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot use SDO_NET. It is ad hoc task and I have to work with our geographical data as they are.

Comment: Then you must just do a few rounds. Select blue lines which are touching the green ones OR which are touching the blue lines which are touching the green ones OR ... If you know how complex your network is you can decide beforehand how many rounds you must do. General solution would be to count the number of selected lines and stop when the latest round did not add any new lines to selection.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about the problem as you wrote but I never worked with PL/SQL so I need your help.

Comment: Sorry, I know only basics of SQL and nothing at all about PL/SQL. If the task is one-off I would copy everything from thin_lines into new table "temp". I would make a "t_1" table from the first generation touches between "temp" and "thick_lines". Delete from "temp" where temp.id=t_1.id. Create a new table "t_2" from the second generation touches - lines remaining in "temp" touching lines in "t_1". Delete from "temp" where temp.id=t_2.id. Continue to "t_3" and so on. Must feel stupid for real SQL folks but the result should be correct.

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking about something like you but it will be my last choise :-).

Comment: in PostGIs there is st_startpoint and st_endpoint, so where st_endpoint(blue_line) = st_startpoint(green_line) AND ... other combinations of end and startpoints. This usable for use case s ehre you try to create noded network table

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle the lines which are directly connected to other lines can be found with the 
Use SDO_TOUCH operator http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10826/sdo_operat.htm

The query will be like

```
SELECT thin.* from thin_lines thin, thick_lines thick 
WHERE
SDO_TOUCH(thin.geom,thick.geom)='TRUE';
```

The problem in this question is more complicated because the aim is to find also non-direct connections: line A-B is connected to line B-C which is connected to line C-D. Lines A-B and C-D are distinct but they are logically connected via linking element B-C. All this is something what is handled with graphs and in Oracle graphs and networks are handled with a specially priced SDO_NET package.

Without specialized network tools the problem must be solved by iterating: Select all blue lines which are touching the green ones OR which are touching the blue lines which are touching the green ones OR ... If you know how complex your network is you can decide beforehand how many rounds you must do. General solution would be to count the number of selected lines and stop when the latest round did not add any new lines to selection.

If SDO_NET license feel too expansive there are also free, open source graph tools. Most famous is probably pgRouting for PostGIS but Virtual Network in Spatialite is also capable for handling your case.

Comment: Sorry, but I know Oracle Spatial operators. I can find blue lines directly connected to the green lines but the problem is, that there are few other blue lines connected to blue line directly connected to green one. A I need to find all blue lines.

Comment: Ok, meanwhile I think could you edit your question? Your aim is not clear from "all blue thin lines connected to the thick green lines".

Comment: Sorry for that, I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

I have found some solution to do this with one query (Oracle 11.2):

```
WITH recursive (p1, p2) AS (
  SELECT thin.connection_id, thin.geom FROM thin_lines thin, thick_lines thick
    WHERE sdo_touch(thin.geom, thick.geom) = 'TRUE' AND thick.color = 'green' AND thin.color = 'blue'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT thin.connection_id, thin.geom FROM thin_lines thin, recursive r
    WHERE sdo_touch(thin.geom, r.p2) = 'TRUE' and thin.color='blue'
)
CYCLE p1 SET is_cycle TO 1 DEFAULT 0
SELECT distinct p1 FROM recursive order by p1;
```

It works, but for small set of thin and thick lines. For huge set it is unusable for me.